# Slicer controls two columns

Tags: powerbi, relational-database, dax, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I'm quite new to Power BI. I have one lookup table and multiple fact tables and their relationships are all one to many.
[image]
I want to create a slicer using **category desc** column from my lookup table. The slicer is going to filter both **category desc** and **old category** columns in a table. Also it is filtering other visuals as a normal filter.

For example if you select golf, the table is going to show **category = golf** or **old category = golf**.
[image]
[image]
Is it possible to just use the slicer from the lookup table which would act as a normal slicer (filtering category desc in my other visuals) while at the same time filter this specific table visual based on the criteria above? Appreciate anyone's help!

```
|Category Desc  |Old Category  |Type  |Amount|
|Golf           |Tennis        |J     |11    |
|Tennis         |Golf          |K     |12    |
|Social         |Fitness       |J     |44    |
|Fitness        |Social        |K     |32    |
|Golf           |Other         |K     |23    |
|Other          |Social        |J     |26    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter only one specific table, then consider using a measure. Something like this.

```
PickThis = 
var _FilterSelect = SELECTEDVALUE('LookupTable'[Label])
return
calculate( countrows('SpecificTable'), FILTER(ALL('SpecificTable'[Category], 'SpecificTable'[OldCategory]), 'SpecificTable'[OldCategory]= _FilterSelect  || 'SpecificTable'[Category] = _FilterSelect ))
```

Comment: When select golf, it gives me something like this:
`
|Category Desc  |Old Category  |Type  |PickThis|
|Golf                   |Tennis             |J         |3          |
|Tennis                |Golf                |K        |3          |
|Social                 |Fitness           |J         |3          |
|Fitness               |Social             |K        |3          |
|Golf                   |Other             |K         |3          |
|Other                |Social             |J          |3          |
`
3 golf for all rows instead of 1 for each row. Any idea?